# Prove that $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$ if and only if $A^2 = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

> Let $A\in M_{n \times n}$ such that rank of $A$ is $1$. Prove that $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$ if and only if $A^2 = 0$.

Comment: You can write $n\times n$; you don't need to write $nxn$ instead. $\qquad$

Comment: Since the statement is not true, you cannot.

Comment: As stated, this isn't even close to true.  Did you leave out some information?

Comment: The "if" part is true, though, for square matrices over any field.

Comment: Forget to mention that rank of A is 1.

Answer (score 5):

This is false.  Consider $A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}$.

**Edit after question edited**:  If $A\in M_{n\times n}$ is rank $1$ then $A=uv^T$ for some $u,v\in M_{n\times 1}$.  We also know that $\operatorname{trace}(A) = u^Tv=u\cdot v$ (can you see why?).  So the condition that this matrix is traceless is that $u^Tv=0=v^Tu$.  Then $$A^2 = (uv^T)(uv^T) = u(v^Tu)v^T = 0$$ by associativity of matrix multiplication. $\ \ \ \square$

Comment: Beat me by 5 seconds :P

Comment: Why $trace(A)=u^{T}v$?

Comment: @VictorManuelGrijalvaAltamir $u^Tv = u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + \cdots + u_nv_n = v^Tu$ and $$A=uv^T = \pmatrix{u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_n}\pmatrix{v_1 & \cdots & v_n} = \pmatrix{u_1v_1 & u_1v_2 & \cdots & u_1v_n \\ u_2v_1 & u_2v_2 & \cdots & u_2v_n \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ u_nv_1 & u_nv_2 & \cdots & u_nv_n}$$  Now look at the trace of that matrix and compare.